# Array in Array and Output

Tags: java

hope you are well. This is my first post here with some basic question about **Array** in Java.

```
int arr[] = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
int n = 6;
n = arr[arr[n]];
System.out.println(n);
```

Someone can explain this to me, why the output is **8**?

Comment: Try to understand that by using one more variable - assign `arr[n]` to `v` or something and see what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

As you are using following code :

```
        int arr[] = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        int n = 6;
        n = arr[arr[n]];
        System.out.println(n);
```

By the above code

```
n=arr[arr[6]];
```

the value of arr[6]=7

```
n=arr[7];
```

As we can see the value of **arr[7] = 8**

Answer (score 2):

```
int arr[] = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        int n = 6;
        n = arr[arr[n]];
        System.out.println(n);
```

`arr[n] with n == 6` -> the 7th element of your array, which is 7 (array indices are 0 based)
`arr[7]` -> the 7th element of your array, being 8

Comment: Right! I tried to solve this only with one Array, but didn't consider the second one! Now it's seems to be clear!

Comment: I mean with code n = arr[arr[n]]; I need to check one Array twice. Hope I wrote it well this time :)

Comment: Yes, that code is actually equivalent to: int x = arr[n]; int n = arr[x];

Answer (score 2):

First it will calculate the value of inner arr[n] which is arr[6], the value of this will be 7. Next it will substitute this value and your expression will evaluate to arr[7] which is 8.

Hence the final answer is 8.

The evaluation sequence is inner to outer.

Answer (score 1):

Concentrate this line `n = arr[arr[n]]; n=6 let int temp=arr[n]; so n=arr[temp]; as n=6 temp=arr[6]=7; temp=7; Now n=arr[temp]=arr[7]=8;`

`Array start with 0 so arr[0]=1,arr[1]=2 ... arr[6]=7`

**Final output arr[7]=8**

Answer (score 1):

```
    n = arr[arr[n]];
```

is equivalent to

```
    n = arr[n]; // start with index 6 and pick value 7
    n = arr[n]; // start with index 7 and pick value 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it helps.  The `-->` should be read as `the same as`.

```
int arr[] = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
for (int n = 0; arr[n] < arr.length; n++) {
       System.out.println("n = " +n + ", arr[" + n + "] = " + arr[n] + ", arr[arr[" + n +"]] --> arr[" + arr[n] + "] = " +arr[arr[n]]);
}
```

prints

```
n = 0, arr[0] = 1, arr[arr[0]] --> arr[1] = 2
n = 1, arr[1] = 2, arr[arr[1]] --> arr[2] = 3
n = 2, arr[2] = 3, arr[arr[2]] --> arr[3] = 4
n = 3, arr[3] = 4, arr[arr[3]] --> arr[4] = 5
n = 4, arr[4] = 5, arr[arr[4]] --> arr[5] = 6
n = 5, arr[5] = 6, arr[arr[5]] --> arr[6] = 7
n = 6, arr[6] = 7, arr[arr[6]] --> arr[7] = 8
n = 7, arr[7] = 8, arr[arr[7]] --> arr[8] = 9
```